# Why can't I post any replies here?

Tags: discussion

I want to help out people with their problems and I can't post comments..

"You're not meeting the right requirements to perform this action"

Comment: you need to have more than 50 points to post coments, untill then you can post answers

Comment: @ZIMRO for example, comments like the one you just left are not considered appropriate. that limit is to prevent such comments

Comment: I understand now

Comment: You may also find this useful: [Full list of privileges and their reputation requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). You can also get a link to this from the trophy icon in the upper right, which also has a link to the list of badges.

Answer (score 2):

Because [commenting is a privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) that is earned at **50** reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You need reputation, which you earn in other ways like answering questions. This is to prevent bad behaviour from new users.